# Run Python script in Python environment?

Tags: python

In the terminal when starting Python, can we run a Python script under Python environment?

I know I can run it on bash, but don't know if I can run it in Python environment. The purpose is to see when the script goes wrong, the values of the variables at that time.

Comment: In the Python console you can `import mymodule` if it's in the current working directory or one in the `sys.path` list.

Answer (score 4):

> The purpose is to see when the script goes wrong, the values of the variables at that time.

You have two options for that (neither of which is precisely the question you're asking, but is nonetheless the proper way to achieve the desired outcome)

---

First, the [`pdb` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

This enters the debugger at whatever point you place this code. Useful for seeing variables.

---

Second, running the command with `-i`:

```
$ python -i script.py
```

This drops into the full interpreter after execution, with all variables intact